# Ignite: First 10 long running cache futures

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, apacheignite

I am running Ignite nodes and during my operation it show this warning and my service become unresponsive how to resolve this!

```
12:18:10,035 [grid-timeout-worker-#39] WARN
org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - First 10 long running cache futures
[total=1]
12:18:10,035 [grid-timeout-worker-#39] WARN
org.apache.ignite.internal.diagnostic - >>> Future [startTime=00:16:20.109,
curTime=00:18:10.030, fut=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture [reqState=Primary
[id=06dc8f4f-b33a-45c1-8c0d-c6a62527fae1, opRes=true, expCnt=4, rcvdCnt=3,
primaryRes=false, done=false,
waitFor=[1e36906c-fae5-49a3-b67a-9eed6ada7e4e],
rcvd=[de1a8ef5-f0ca-41b1-87f5-dfe9f4517fab,
48cc4679-c256-4666-a39d-76fbd915ac02,
f0f38fba-4963-42dd-a64e-774057a61044]],
super=GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture [remapCnt=100,
topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=7, minorTopVer=0], remapTopVer=null,
err=null, futId=1, super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false,
state=INIT, res=null, hash=316835640]]]]
```

Comment: Most likely this atomic cache update is blocked by a PME. Full logs would be helpful here.